# How to add dynamically "@import" into all my scss files with Angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular, sass

I have multiple scss files in my project, all of them need to import different scss files because I'm working with variables.
I could add them myself but I'm using a library to transform json data to scss variables, so if I add the @imports myself, when I add more data to the json and I update the scss, the "@import" I added is deleted. That's why I need add them dynamically.

For example, I need to add **@import "colors.scss"** and "**typography.scss"** to my "components.scss"

**component.scss**

```
@import "colors.scss"
@import "typography.scss"
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: $color-white;
}
```

How could I do that considering I have many scss files?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you considered Forward and Use instead of imports?

Comment: I haven't but in that case, I would need to add the @use into the scss files too

Comment: Check out this video. It will explain what I meant by my comment. Watch it all the way through, it will show you how to do what you are trying to do. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CR-a8upNjJ0&list=PLlwbAGSVMKHrkw8qJHSXePgvYRwy9i-8Q&index=42&t=1s